# Interpolate the values at the contour points

Tags: c++, opencv, interpolation

Given : List of ordered points (2D) representing a closed contour 
Current Status : The points on the contour are sampled (uniformly or arbitrarily) and some value (say descriptor of some sort) is computed for each point.

Task :  I would like to interpolate the the value calculated at the sampled points to the points which are not in the sample. Perhaps I can take 3 sampled points in order and interpolate their values to the non-sampled points which lie between the two extreme points of the chosen 3 points. I reading bunch of papers but getting extremely confused as to what to do: interpolate a curve (Catmul Rom for example) or a surface. Perhaps there is some C++ library which does what I want or some ideas.

To clarify futher:

Set of 2d points in the contour (The last points joins back to the first point), si = (xi,yi)

```
s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7 ,s8, s9, s10, s11 , s12 , s13, s14, s15
```

Sampled points

```
s0          s3          s6          s9             s12             s15
```

Calculate some value at those sampled points

```
f(s0)     f(s3)       f(s6)       f(s9)          f(s12)           f(s15)
```

Now the goal is to find interpolated values at the other points

```
     s1 s2     s4 s5       s7 s8        s10  s11       s13  s14
```

Comment: If your points are on a plane (2D) and you try to get a contour line (1D) why would you want to interpolate a surface (usually a 2D thingy in a 3D space)?

Comment: I would go for [splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: @tobi303 I have edited the question for further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some simple weighted average. 
For example say you have a point X between A and B a distance function d and a property p you can get do

```
p(X) = ( p(A) * d(X, A) + p(B) * d(X,B) ) / (d(X,A) + d(X,B))
```

You can do the same with 3 points (A, B and C) if you want more curvy results (the example above is going to be linear).

These should be OK approximations, unless you know more about the original curve. If you don't know anything about the original curve there's no way to predict the values perfectly.